# Google Earth on Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, google-earth

I have downloaded Google Earth 7.1.2, and I am trying to install it on Fedora 19. The error I am getting is:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin from install of google-earth-stable-7.1.2.2041-0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-13.fc19.x86_64
```

Please help.

Comment: If it works, could you please select my answer? Ty

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is well-known bug for Fedora, affecting both 18 and 19. You can read about it [here](https://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/issues/detail?id=1525). It is basically a complaint that your GE package is attempting to do something (most likely, installing some programs) with /usr/bin, which is owned by another package. The notion of `ownership` of /usr/bin sounds very strange to me, it seems reasonable that this is security issue, but I do not knwow of any way to solve it. A workaround for Fedora 19 is provided toward the end of the page I referenced above,

```
 yum install http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/18/i386/rpmrebuild-2.9-1.fc18.noarch.rpm
```

Careful, some of the work-arounds suggested for Fedora 18 early in the thread are later said to be useless in Fedora 19. The only one known work-around for Fedora 19, AFAIK, is the one above.

Comment: FYI, I just installed rpmrebuild-2.9-1.fc19.noarch.rpm from a normal F19 updates repo via 'yum install rpmrebuild'.